How to chose a timezone for the Django Q cron scheduler
I am using Django-Q to create scheduled tasks through a CRON setup.
I would need the schedule to have a timezone information.
Example : "30 8 * * 1" with UTC would be 8:30 UTC (regardless of the Django timezone defined in my settings)
Will I need to create a cluster per timezone and define them as broker depending on the task timezone ?
